# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: appium

I am getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'Himanshus-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.72', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
```

I am currently running 2 eclipses and 2 appium server with both different ports.

```
Appium version : v.13

Port 1 : 0.0.0.0: 4734

Port 2 : 127.0.0.1: 4723

java-client - 6.1.0

selenium-java - 3.13.0
```

I have configured 2 different bootstrap ports.

I've also added a different `systemPort` number in `DesiredCapability`.

If I am missing anything, please do let me know.

Comment: I guess Appium v.13 is it 1.13.0, right?

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Both the appium version are 1.13.0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your versions do not fit together. You need to upgrade your [java-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0) to a later version. Probably to version `7.0.0` or `7.0.1`.
Remember to upgrade other dependencies as well like Selenium.

I suggest to use following versions:

- Selenium: 3.141.59
- java-client: 7.0.1
- appium server: 1.14.0

If this does not solve your problem please attach the Appium server log as well.

Comment: After updating it to java cline 7.0.1 and appium server to 1.14.1 as Beta version is out. Getting a lot of staleElementException.

Comment: Don't use the beta version of you face issues with it.

Comment: If you still get the StaleElementReferenceExceptions you can take a look at this answer from me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513438/7450414
It works in a similar way with the AppiumDriver. If you cannot solve it then, please ask a new question.